# Multiple Editing Support in SWTTable

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, tableviewer

I have an SWT Table, It contains 2 columns

1. Name
2. Value

I want to have multiple cell editors on the value column , I get the multiple editors but when I change some value in a cell and want to change it again the cell editors does not appear again. My code

```
 valueColumn.setEditingSupport(new EditingSupport(viewer) {         
        @Override
        protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
            String type = (Parameter) element.getValue();
            if (type.equals("file")) {
                return new FileEditingSupport(viewer).getCellEditor(element);
            } else if(type.equals("dir")) {
                return new DirectoryEditingSupport(viewer).getCellEditor(element);
            } else if(type.equals("boolean")){
                return new ComboBoxEditingSupport(viewer).getCellEditor(element);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
            if (element != null && value != null) {
                Parameter entry = (Parameter)element;
                entry.setValue(value.toString());
                viewer.refresh();
            }
        }           
        @Override
        protected Object getValue(Object element) {
            return ((Parameter)element).getValue();
        }   
    });
```

The FileEditingSupport Class

```
public class FileEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {

private final TableViewer viewer;

public FileEditingSupport(TableViewer viewer) {
    super(viewer);
    this.viewer = viewer;
}

@Override
public CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
    return new FileBrowseCellEditor(this.viewer, (Parameter) element);
}

@Override
protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected Object getValue(Object element) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
}

}
```

I can select the file once but when I select one file and want to change it gain I dont get the file picker cell editor

Comment: `Object` does not have a `getValue` method so how does `element.getValue()` even compile?

Comment: element is of Type Parameter and Parameter has a method getValue()

Comment: @greg-449 I edited the code can you have a look now?

Comment: Well it looks like you are saving the file path in the element with `setValue` so the next time you call `getValue` it won't be `file`, `dir` or `boolean` and you return null for the editor.

Comment: Thanks you are right